# Laravel 5.5 and .htaccess - images and css files are not loading

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a brand new virtual server with `Apache2`. I'm trying to start my `Laravel 5.5` project.

It's working fine in my Homestead enviroment, but on this server it isn't work.

I'm using this apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.myproject.com
    ServerAlias myproject.com new.myproject.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myadmin.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.myproject.com/current/public
    CustomLog /var/www/www.myproject.com/log/access.log vhost_combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/www.myproject.com/log/error.log
    RewriteEngine On
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /var/www/www.myproject.com/current/public/index.php [L]
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/www.myproject.com/current/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the main page is loaded well, but if I click on Login or Register menu, witch are a Laravel handled and Blade template based pages it's showed, but the CSS, JS and images are not loading. Files are sitting on their place in public/ folder, they are not null-sized, and still not loading.

If I click on login page, instead of these files (css, js, images) the login pages showed...

Has anybody any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace .htaccess with following and create .htaccess file outside public folder.

```
RewriteEngine On


#----------------------------------------------
# | this code use for remove public directory |
#----------------------------------------------




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.ico|\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.eot|\.svg|\.ttf|\.woff|\.woff2|\.otf|\.pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(login|uploads|assets|css|js|images|ca|favicons|fonts|)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]


RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(login|uploads` Why are login and uploads on this list?